# Summer 16 Canvas Error with Lightning Locker Service Enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I have a lightning component on the app exchange that provides a canvas element for the user to draw their signature. In a Summer 16 pre-release org with the lightning locker service enabled, when I attempt to get the drawing context via :

```
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
```

I get the following error:

```
    TypeError: this.canvas.getContext is not a function. (In 
      'this.canvas.getContext("2d")', 'this.canvas.getContext' is undefined)
```

Comment: Thanks Bob - I've opened a bug to track getting this fixed - it missed the cutoff for the patch deploying Tuesday but I will get the fix in for the following week.

Comment: I am trying to see if I can still get this into next weeks patch - just under the wire - stay tuned

Comment: Any help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance.
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129883/in-chart-js-mouse-hover-is-not-working-locker-service-enabled-org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed and I'm able to create a context, allow the user to draw into at and extract a data URL from it.

Comment: Bob, I've a different kind of issue but is related to Canvas. Can you take a look at my query and let me know if you have encountered this and have any workaround for this issue with `<canvas>` elements and LockerService - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/lockerservice-in-lightning-components-is-blocking-canvas-element-color-fill-comp