# LockerService in Lightning Components is blocking Canvas element color fill completely

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, bug, locker-service

When `LockerService` is activated, it makes `<canvas>` element unusable.

And if I deactivate `LockerService`, it would display `<canvas>` in filled color.

Consider following code and actual result I'm getting with `LockerService`.

**CanvasColorTest.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
    
    <ltng:require styles="/resource/advpm__slds_v0110/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system-ltng.min.css"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.performInit}" />
    
    <canvas class="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
    </canvas>
    
</aura:component>
```

**CanvasColorTestController.js**

```
({
    performInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        
        var c = document.querySelector(".myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(20, 20, 150, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(40, 40, 150, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();

    }
})
```

Now, above code generates following output:

- `LockerService` - ***Deactivated***

[image]

- `LockerService` - ***Activated***

[image]

Is there any way I can get `<canvas>` element with color fill working in Lightning Components, with `LockerService` enabled?

Could this be a bug or just intentional from Salesforce Team?

I'm also seeing following JS Warning/Error in Chrome Developer Console:

> aura_prod.js:456
>
> 'CanvasRenderingContext2D.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled' is deprecated.
> Please use 'CanvasRenderingContext2D.imageSmoothingEnabled' instead.

***This particular Error Message also only appears when LockerService is activated in the org.***

Answer (score 1):

Possibly related to this bug: [Can't set element.style.properties in JS inside Lightning Locker](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127032/cant-set-element-style-properties-in-js-inside-lightning-locker)

Your code works fine on my sandbox with Locker enabled and I get the blue/red rectangles. I suspect this has to do with some of the object property bugs that were supposed to be fixed recently. Perhaps the fix has not rolled out to your org yet but it should get there eventually.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the situation. This was fixed last week.

Comment: Thanks for the info Charles and Trevor. Is there any date on which can production and dev orgs have the fix deployed? I ve a broken lightning component in susbcriber org due this :-)

Comment: You should be able to disable Lightning Locker on any org. Certainly if you already have Lightning components in production you should not yet enable Locker until you have verified in sandboxes that Locker does not break your components.

Comment: I just wanted to add, I don't have a date for you as I don't work for SF but I can report that my sandbox is on the CS2 instance which has been upgraded to Summer '16 Patch 10. And it looks like all sandboxes are on Patch 10. So try this in a sandbox and hopefully you'll see that it's fixed too. In the meantime disable Locker in production and keep it off until you're satisfied it does not break anything else in production.

Comment: Looks like both production and sandboxes are now up to Patch 10.3.